# Extract Distinct restful MVC routes from IIS logs

Tags: iis-7, logging, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc

This is a [cross post from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809056/exctract-distinct-restful-mvc-routes-from-iis-logs) that after some consideration I believe can be asked here (not getting anything on SO).

My shop is using MVC3/FUBU on IIS 7. I recently put something into production and I wanted to gather metrics from the IIS logs using log parser. I've done this many times before with file endpoints but because the MVC3 routes are of the form `/api/person/{personid}/address/{addressid}` the log saves `/api/person/123/address/456` in the uristem column.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get data about specific routes from IIS logs?

As an exmaple: Log Like this:

```
cs-uri-stem
/api/person/123/address/456
/api/person/121/address/33
/api/person/3555
/api/person/1555/address/5555
```

I want information about all where the route used was `/api/person/{personid}` so the count would be 1 in this case.

Ideally what I'd like to figure out is how to do is is have IIS log the regex for the route that is choose for a particular url. So in the IIS logs have `/api/person/{personid}/address/{addressid}` in a column in addition to the cs-uristem `/api/person/1555/address/5555`